# Issue on Highchaert Fill Opacity and Legend Color on Spiderweb

Tags: highcharts

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/przJs/) and let me know :
1- why the Legend Color still showing the lines color while I already changed the chart type to :

```
type: 'area'
```

and fill color for the series as:

```
fillColor: 'yellow',
```

2- I am not also set the opacity working. As you can see in the following code:

```
 series: [{
        name: 'Allocated Budget',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        fillColor: 'red',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    }, {
        name: 'Actual Spending',
        data: [50000, 39000, 42000, 31000, 26000],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        fillColor: 'yellow',
        fillOpacity: 0.2
    }]
```

I used the `fillOpacity: 0.2` to have a semi transparent area but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answers for you:

1. Because you have set `fillColor` not `color`. Set `color` to change color in legend.
2. `fillOpacity` works only with `#XXYYZZ` colors.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/przJs/1/