# Highcharts - Can't change line colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm looking to change the spider lines of the Highcharts spider web graph. I'm using a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/przJs/1/) by [someone else](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24740037/6365534) since mine isn't working for some reason.

I want to be able to change the line colors of the spider lines. What property do I change to get that?

```
$('#emotion-ranking-graph-bar').highcharts({
    chart: {
        polar: true,
        type: 'line',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.0)'
    },
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    },
    title: {
        text: '',
        x: 0
    },
    pane: {
        size: '80%'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Joy', 'Sorrow', 'Anger', 'Seriousness',
                'Information Technology', 'Administration'],
        tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
        lineWidth: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: true
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        gridLineInterpolation: 'polygon',
        lineWidth: 0,
        min: 0,
        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        shared: true,
        pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}: <b>${point.y:,.0f}</b><br/>'
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Emotional Analysis Spectrum',
        data: [43000, 19000, 60000, 35000, 17000, 10000],
        pointPlacement: 'on',
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.7)'
    }]
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines going from the center to the outside are the `yAxis`, and the lines making the pentagon are the `xAxis`. You have to change the `gridLineColor` option on both:

http://jsfiddle.net/przJs/41/

Here you have a lot of options to fiddle: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.gridLineColor

Comment: Thank you, how do you change the thickness of series lines in a spider web graph?

Comment: That's the `lineWidth` parameter and can be applied in 2 ways. By adding it to the series that you want to change the thickness or via `plotOptions` to the series type that you want to apply it (`line`, in this case), and will apply to all the series of that type. Open the link I posted and write in the search box at the left `lineWidth`, and you will see all the locations where you can apply it. There's also (usually) a "try it" option below each explanation that opens a fiddle where you can see it in action.

Comment: Thank you, I'm just getting used to the docs but will continue to search. For the thickness and color of the points on the graph, what property would I use for that?

Comment: For the points, you should look for `markers`. There are tons of options to play with. There are also `hover` options when markers are hovered, too.